# awk to print lines matching criteria

Tags: awk

I am trying to print out all lines in which `$1` is `intronic|UTR3|UTR5` and `$2` matches a certain pattern `[^*+-]+[*+-]`. I think the `awk` below is close but my `current output` is a column of `1`.  I can remove these lines but not seem to print them.  The input file is tab-delimeted. Thank you :).

**strong text**

```
Func.refGene    Mutation Call   Mutant Allele Frequency
1   intronic    c.[434-90G>C]+[=]   52.93
1   intronic    c.[433+79A>G]+[433+79A>G]   100
1   intronic    c.[1017+56G>A]+[1017+56G>A] 100
1   exonic  c.[1119G>A]+[=] 100
5   UTR3    c.[*68A>G]+[=]  51.46
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '
$1 ~ "^(intronic|UTR3|UTR5)$" {
v=$2
sub(/^[^*+-]+[*+-]/,"",v)
if(v + 0 > 10)
  print sub(/^[^*+-]+[*+-]/,"",v)
}1' file
```

**current output**

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

**desired output**

```
1   intronic    c.[434-90G>C]+[=]   52.93
1   intronic    c.[433+79A>G]+[433+79A>G]   100
1   intronic    c.[1017+56G>A]+[1017+56G>A] 100
5   UTR3    c.[*68A>G]+[=] 51.46
```

Comment: You seem to say only **intronic|UTR3|UTR5** to be matched. Your desired output shows exonic as successful match. Do you want exonic to be matched?

Comment: My apologies @blackpen those are what I am trying to output, I corrected the post output. Thank you :).

Comment: The script & input do not produce the output shown.  Also `sub` returns the number of replacements, not the processed string.

Comment: I suspect your regexp `^[^*+-]+[*+-]` doesn't do what you think it does since every line of your input will match that regexp. If you tell us what you are trying to do and which line it's meant to NOT match against (add that line to your sample input if it's missing) then we can help you write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking for something like the following. Suggest corrections if your matching needs to be adjusted. I tried the following with GNU Awk. Store the following file into script.awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
   FS="[ \t]+";
}

{
   if ($2 ~ /^(intronic|UTR3|UTR5)$/ ) {
      print "Matched Mutation Call:" $2;

      if ($3 ~ /^[^*+-]+[*+-]/) {
         print "Matched Mutant Allele :" $3;

         if ($4 > 10) {
             print "Matched Freq:" $4;
             print "Matched Record:" $0;
         }

      }

   }
   print "END OF RECORD\n";
}
```

You run it as:

```
cat data | ./script.awk
```

If you have more searching/programming needs, it woulnd't hurt to learn perl as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

while (my $line=<>) {
   print "\nBEGIN OF RECORD\n";

   chomp($line);
   my @F=split(/\s+/,$line);

   if ($F[1]=~/^(intronic|UTR3|UTR5)$/) {
      print "Matched Mutation Call:".$F[1]."\n";

      if ($F[2]=~/^[^*+-]+[*+-]/) {
         print "Matched Mutant Allele :".$F[2]."\n";

         if ($F[3] > 10) {
             print "Matched Freq:".$F[3]."\n";
             print "Matched Record:".$line."\n";
         }
      }
   }
   print "END OF RECORD\n";
}
```

You coudl run it as:

```
cat data | ./script.pl
```

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help and explanations :).

Comment: wrt the awk, no need to specifcy a FS, the default works fine, and you don't need the trailing semicolons. wrt calling either solution google UUOC.

Comment: The above `awk` script contains nothing GNU `awk` specific and can be used with any implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to print out all lines in which $1 is intronic|UTR3|UTR5

In your sample input there are no lines in which $1 is intronic|UTR3|UTR5 . In all lines $1 is either 1 or 5 or "Func.refGene" .

> and $2 matches a certain pattern [^*+-]+[*+-].

In your sample input there are no lines in which $2 matches this pattern.  In all lines, $2 is "Mutation Call", "intronic", "exonic", or "UTR3".

It some lines, however, $2 is `intronic|UTR3|UTR5`, and $3 matches `[^*+-]+[*+-]`.  If that is what you want, you need:

```
awk -F'\t' '$2 ~ "^(intronic|UTR3|UTR5)$" && $3 ~ "[^*+-]+[*+-]"' file
```

That produces your desired output.

However, are you sure you understand what does the pattern `[^*+-]+[*+-]` mean?  It means: 1 or more of any characters except `[*+-]`, followed by `[*+-]`. This means the same as `[^*+-][*+-]` .   Likely, you mean some other pattern.

Finally, your program has almost nothing to do with what you wrote you want.  Either you want something completely different, or your program makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Awk field numbers (and string and array indices) start at 1, not 0:

```
$ awk '($2~/^(intronic|UTR[35])$/) && ($3~/^[^*+-]+[*+-]/) && ($4>10)' file
1   intronic    c.[434-90G>C]+[=]   52.93
1   intronic    c.[433+79A>G]+[433+79A>G]   100
1   intronic    c.[1017+56G>A]+[1017+56G>A] 100
5   UTR3    c.[*68A>G]+[=]  51.46
```

but every $3 in your sample input contains a `[*+-]` character and has characters that are `[^*+-]` before it so either that regexp is wrong or your input doesn't cover the cases that it's meant to exclude from the output. As-is it's doing nothing.